# Make a copy of an object's value without copying the reference

Tags: php, object, reference, clone

I have the following code:

```
$data['x'] = $this->x->getResults();  

$data['y'] = $data['x'];

//some code here to modify $data['y']
//this causes (undesirably) $data['x] to be modified as well
```

I guess since all the elements of $data are themselves references, modifying `$data['y']` also modifies `$data['x']` which is NOT what I want.  I want `$data['x']` to remain the same.  Is there any way to dereference the elements here so that I can copy the elements by value?

Update:

`$this->x->getResults();` returns an object array.  So I can then do something like: `$data['x'][0]->date_create` ...

**Update**:
my latest attempt to clone the array looks something like this:

```
$data['x'] = $this->x->getResults();     
$data['y'] = $data['y'];
foreach($data['x'] as $key=>$row) {
    $data['y'][$key]->some_attr = clone $row->some_attr;
}
```

Am I way off here? I keep getting a "__clone method called on non-object" error.  From reading the responses it seems like my best option is to iterate over each element and clone it (which is what I was trying to do with that code..).

Comment: What is `$this->x->getResults()` returning? An object?

Comment: It would be important to know what `$this->x->getResults()` returns...

Comment: yes, I am using codeigniter so that is a call to a model (x) which returns an object array of database query results

Comment: Then you must clone every object in that array of objects.

Comment: When writing your own classes, internal variable references are not cloned by default. You must implement the clone function, eg: `public function __clone() { $this->widget = clone $this->widget(); }` for each reference inside your object that should be cloned as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that PHP will dereference the results of a function call.

Here's some example code I whipped up:

```
$x = 'x';
$y = 'y';
$arr = array(&$x,&$y);
print_r($arr);

echo "<br/>";
$arr2 = $arr;
$arr2[0] = 'zzz';
print_r($arr);
print_r($arr2);

echo "<br/>";
$arr2 = array_flip(array_flip($arr));
$arr2[0] = '123';
print_r($arr);
print_r($arr2);
```

The results look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => x [1] => y )
Array ( [0] => zzz [1] => y ) Array ( [0] => zzz [1] => y )
Array ( [0] => zzz [1] => y ) Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => y )
```

You can see that the results of using `array_flip()` during the assigment of `$arr` to `$arr2` results in differences in the subsequent changes to `$arr2`, as the `array_flip()` calls forces a dereference.

It doesn't seem terribly efficient, but it might work for you if `$this->x->getResults()` is returning an array:

```
$data['x'] = array_flip(array_flip($this->x->getResults()));
$data['y'] = $data['x'];
```

See [this (unanswered) thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894814/deep-copy-of-php-array-of-references) for another example.

If everything in your returned array is an object however, then the only way to copy an object is to use `clone()`, and you would have to iterate through `$data['x']` and clone each element into `$data['y']`.

Example:

```
$data['x'] = $this->x->getResults();
$data['y'] = array();
foreach($data['x'] as $key => $obj) {
    $data['y'][$key] = clone $obj;
}
```

Comment: I am having some trouble with this: like you mentioned in your last sentence, everything in my returned array is an object..could you maybe post some code showing how to iterate over the array and clone each element?  I keep getting a "_clone method called on non-object" error.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I added an example.  `clone` only works on actual objects, so if the return result of `$this->x->getResults();` is an array of objects instead of an object, then you can't clone the array, you have to clone each element of the array separately.

Comment: `array_flip` is not a good idea!! If you have 2 keys with the same value then the first key will be lost when the `array_flip` function is called.

Comment: a bit of mis-information here.   the function return doesn't do a deep-dereferencing.    the magic above is the `array_flip(array_flip($array))`..

Answer (score 10):

`array_merge()` can accept any number of parameters, even 1, then produce a new array. So just do following:

```
$new_array = array_merge($existing_array);
```

Answer (score 7):

`array_flip()` won't work when array values are not strings nor integers.
I found a simple solution, however:

```
$clonedArr = (array)clone(object)$arr;
```

This works thanks to the properties of clone on an object.

Comment: This does not work. If `$arr` has reference variables in it, the new array will still have them. References survive cloning.

Answer (score 3):

Not simple. 
Read about [clone](http://us.php.net/clone)

BUT! if your elements are **not objects** and **not refence type variables** you have no problem.

Example for reference types:

```
$v=11;
$arr[]=&$v;
```

Comment: why is it that I only have a problem if the elements are objects? is it because objects are themselves references?

Comment: In PHP, (as of version 5 IICRC) all objects are passed by reference by default.

Comment: This answer is not quite true.  It should read "If your elements are not references, you have no problem.".  You can have references that are not objects.

Comment: Objects aren't references, they're technically pointers, but they appear to act like references.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with objects, you might want to take a look at [`clone`](http://php.net/clone), to create a **copy** of an object, instead of a **reference**.

Here is a very short example :

First, with an array, it works by value :

```
$data['x'] = array(
    'a' => 'test',
    'b' => 'glop',
);
$data['y'] = $data['x'];
$data['y'][0] = 'Hello, world!';
var_dump($data['x']); // a => test : no problem with arrays
```

By default, with objects, it works by reference :

```
$data['x'] = (object)array(
    'a' => 'test',
    'b' => 'glop',
);
$data['y'] = $data['x'];
$data['y']->a = 'Hello, world!';
var_dump($data['x']); // a => Hello, world! : objects are by ref
```

But, if you clone the object, you work on a copy :

*I guess this is your case ?*

```
$data['x'] = (object)array(
    'a' => 'test',
    'b' => 'glop',
);
$data['y'] = clone $data['x'];
$data['y']->a = 'Hello, world!';
var_dump($data['x']); // a => test : no ref, because of cloning
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks for the code sample..do you know if the clone function is relatively efficient?  I ask because I know that in java it is usually best to avoid this if possible.

Comment: I have no idea about the efficiency, but if you need the functionnality, it doesn't really matter, does it ? (and, considering you are doing a DB query just a while before, it shouldn't be that long, in comparison with the rest of the script :-) )

Comment: I think the only inherent inefficiency would be due to the fact that you are doubling the amount of memory in order to store the same object twice. Thus, it is only as inefficient as copying any other variable would be.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that if you simply want a copy of an array of values (no references) from a constant then you can just write:

$new_array = (array) (object) self::old_array;

Not an exact answer to the OP's question but it helped me and might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function to copy multidimensional arrays containing objects.

```
<?php
function arrayCopy( array $array ) {
    $result = array();
    foreach( $array as $key => $val ) {
        if( is_array( $val ) ) {
            $result[$key] = arrayCopy( $val );
        } elseif ( is_object( $val ) ) {
            $result[$key] = clone $val;
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't `clone` do a shallow copy?  So it won't recurse to any array properties.

Comment: Yes it won't. So i guess if there are any array properties containing some more objects you could use `__clone()` to let the objects themselves figure out how exactly they should be cloned.