# PHP dereference array elements

Tags: php, arrays, reference, dereference

I have 2 arrays.

```
$result = array();
$row = array();
```

Row's elements are all references and is constantly changing. For each iteration of `$row` I want to copy the **values** of row into an entry of `$result` and not the references.

I have found a few solutions but they all seem rather awful.

```
$result[] = unserialize(serialize($row));
$result[] = array_flip(array_flip($row));
```

Both of the above work but seem like a lot of unnecessary and ugly code just to copy the contents of an array of references by value, instead of copying the references themselves.

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this? If not what would the most efficient way be?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** As suggested below something such as:

```
function dereference($ref) {
    $dref = array();

    foreach ($ref as $key => $value) {
        $dref[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $dref;
}

$result[] = dereference($row);
```

Also works but seems equally as ugly.

Comment: This might be a duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190026/php-copying-array-elements-by-value-not-by-reference

Comment: He is dealing with objects. I am dealing strictly with arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy"? Which kind of "references" are you talking about that should be avoided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I totally understand the question, but can you use recursion?

```
function array_copy($source) {
    $arr = array();

    foreach ($source as $element) {
        if (is_array($element)) {
            $arr[] = array_copy($element);
        } else {
            $arr[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}

$result = array();
$row = array(
    array('a', 'b', 'c'),
    array('d', 'e', 'f')
);

$result[] = array_copy($row);

$row[0][1] = 'x';

var_dump($result);
var_dump($row);
```

Comment: it appears as though your function would indeed work and what I suggested was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the function above like follows solved a problem I had:

```
function array_copy($source) {
    $arr = array();

    foreach ($source as $element) {
        if (is_array($element)) {
            $arr[] = array_copy($element);
        } elseif (is_object($element)) {
            // make an object copy
            $arr[] = clone $element;
        } else {
            $arr[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = array_map(function($_){return $_;}, $row);
```

Comment: Hello DonJaime, welcome to StackOverflow. :-) You seem to have posted a nice answer here. Yet, instead of just posting code as an answer, please add an explanation to your solution, so the readers can also understand why it works.

Comment: How is this different from `$result = $row`?